# Hidden comments not showing with C# Facebook SDK

Tags: c#, facebook, facebook-c#-sdk, facebook-comments, facebook-wall

I am using the Facebook C# SDK to add Facebook functionality to a website.

I can successfully pull a user's wall but for some reason the hidden comments(the comments Facebook hides and instead shows the text "View All X Comments") on a status/whatever aren't in the JSON object returned by the SDK.

I am using code identical to the following to get the JSON object:

```
public JsonObject GetProfileWall(string accessToken, string ProfileID)
{
    FacebookClient client = new FacebookClient(accessToken);
    if (ProfileID.Trim().Length > 0)
    {
        JsonObject me = client.Get(ProfileID + "/feed") as JsonObject;
        return me;
    }
    else
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Is anyone else experiencing a similar issue, or am I missing something stupid?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess is that for each feed post that you encounter after retrieving from `/me/feed` you will need to request their `comments` connection, as outlined in the [Post docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/post/)

I suspect that `/me/feed/` is specifically designed to reproduce the feed view that would be seen on Facebook.com itself. Let me know if this isn't the case and you still can't get those comments.

Comment: Hi Matthew, thank you for your reply. What you said makes a lot of sense - I was under the impression that Facebook would provide all of the comments in the JSON object returned. It seems that I was wrong :).